# Resizing user uploaded images in an ASP.NET project – Library?

Tags: asp.net, image, resize

In a rather simple ASP.NET application where the user can upload a image, mostly from his digital camera. I have to resize it to a workable size for the web and a thumbnail.
What is here the best practice for? Is there a library that I in a simple way can implement without installing something on the web server.

Comment: Do you miss some features, which are not implemented by the classes in the System.Drawing namespace?

Comment: System.Drawing is horribly buggy. [Read this list of 28 image resizing pitfalls before you dive in.](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/) I wrote the [imageresizing.net library](http://imageresizing.net/) to do exactly what you're looking for.  It's simple, and has a 1-line API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread on SO will probably help you decide:

[What is the best image manipulation library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158756/what-is-the-best-image-manipulation-library)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am the author of this library.

However, it was designed exactly for this purpose, and is very mature and well-tested.

http://nathanaeljones.com/products/asp-net-image-resizer/

I think you will find the included sample application does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [BitMap class](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4651/resizing-images-retrieved-from-sql-server/)- you can do this quite easily by specifying the size in the constructor.

So imagine you wanted to half it:

```
Bitmap firstBitMap; // created somewhere else

// Create a new bitmap from the first, scaling down as we go
Bitmap halfSize = new Bitmap(firstBitMap, new Size(firstBitMap.Width/2, firstBitMap.Height/2));
```

If you want a higher quality solution, you need to [consider the InterpolationMode enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0fsyd4e.aspx).

For the simple scenario you describe you certainly don't need to bother with 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I am no image expert, but I implemented image resizing on a website and used something like this:

```
public static void ResizeImageHighQuality(string imgFilename, string imgResizedFilename, int resizeH, int resizeW)
{
    Image img = Image.FromFile(imgFilename);
    int h = 0, w = 0;

    if (img.Width > img.Height)
    {
        w = Convert.ToInt32(resizeW);
        h = Convert.ToInt32(w * Convert.ToDouble(img.Height) / Convert.ToDouble(img.Width));

    }
    else if (img.Height > img.Width)
    {
        h = Convert.ToInt32(resizeH);
        w = Convert.ToInt32(h * Convert.ToDouble(img.Width) / Convert.ToDouble(img.Height));
    }
    else
    {
        h = resizeH;
        w = resizeW;
    }

    Image thumbnail = new Bitmap(w, h);
    Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnail);

    graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    graphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

    graphic.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

    ImageCodecInfo[] Info = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
    EncoderParameters Params = new EncoderParameters(1);
    Params.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);

    File.Delete(imgResizedFilename);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgResizedFilename, FileMode.CreateNew);
    thumbnail.Save(fs, Info[1], Params);
    fs.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Bitmap (and any other System.Drawing classes) is [specifically prohibited in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing(v=vs.110).aspx) (see the warning near the top of the documentation page).

Using them may result in exceptions such as these:

```
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Media.Brush' threw an exception.
   at System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush..ctor(Color color)
   ...
'System.Windows.Media.Transform' threw an exception.
   at System.Windows.Media.Brush..cctor()Win32Exception: The operation completed successfully
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.RegisterClassEx(WNDCLASSEX_D wc_d)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32 exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, String name, IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks)
   at MS.Win32.MessageOnlyHwndWrapper..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.get_CurrentDispatcher()
   at System.Windows.Freezable..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Media.MatrixTransform..ctor(Matrix matrix)
   at System.Windows.Media.Transform..cctor()
```

and

```
Win32Exception: The operation completed successfully
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32 exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, String name, IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContextNotificationWindow..ctor(MediaContext ownerMediaContext)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext..ctor(Dispatcher dispatcher)
```

Depending on what you are trying to do, [Windows Imaging Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719654(v=vs.85).aspx) may fill your need.  We have also had luck by creating a single STA thread and invoking all drawing operations over to that.